# Running MS Access VB Module from ArcCatalog

Tags: ms-access, vba

I created some VBA code that runs a make table query in MS Access. Whenever the MS Access database is opened it automatically runs the SQL and updates the table.
I then created a database connection in Arcatalog to the MS Access database where I can link to the MS Access .accdb file and add the table to ArcMap.

When I have items linked in ArcMap with the db connection I get the .laccdb extension along with the .accdb extension. I was hoping that since arcatalog was linked to the access database that this would trigger the VBA code and re-run the code and update the linked table in ArcMap without having to go into the Access database each time.
I noticed that in the VBA editor window I can click on some ESRI references.

Is there any line of code that I can add that will make the access database run once it is initialized by ArcCatalog via the database connection that I have set up utilizing any of these ESRI references libraries that I see in MS Access?
thanks

Comment: Autoexec macro is started when user interface part of MS Access database started. While connecting to DB and opening linking to its data You don't init user interface part, so autoexec macro is not executed. You may connect this DB to Your application as a library reference (independent of data connection) and then start execution of the code directly.

Comment: Ok thank you Akina. I will look into doing that. That would be adding one of the references in ms access to the code? I need to look for a list of the references to find out which one I need, but I will look into it. Knowing that the macro isnt being executed is a good to know

Comment: Starting Access procedure from VBA (another database, Excel, Word, etc.) looks like `Dim app As Access.Application: Set app = CreateObject("Access.Application"): app.OpenCurrentDatabase (strDatabaseFileName): app.Run strSubName: app.Quit acQuitSaveNone`. Maybe it help You.

Comment: Ok For you're example replace Access.application with the correct referenced one? I see the correct one but I do not think Im setting it up           Option Compare Database
'Public Function Startup() ---commented this out as was used with the macro
Dim app As esriArcMap: Set app = CreateObject("esriArcMap"):


Dim strSql As String

        
        strSql = " My SQL Query"
                 
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSql
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        
End Function

Comment: @Akina - Hmm - your comments look suspiciously like an answer :-)

Comment: @RDFozz No. Answer is to solve the problem. If author decide comment do it, I'll convert.

Comment: *For you're example replace Access.application with the correct referenced one?* It seems You want to execute Access code? If so You need to create Access Application object.

Comment: ok, but if access is closed what will trigger it to open when I am in the esri map software, i need to place this in the CreateObject? I will test out different ways ans see

Comment: But yes I do want access to open when i am using the esri software. thank you Akina

Comment: *ok, but if access is closed what will trigger it to open when I am in the esri map software, i need to place this in the CreateObject?* CreateObject don't need in load user interface. But all modules nesessary to work with Access.Application will be loaded.

Comment: Ok. Im doing it the way you described.  It  doesnt like this line app.OpenCurrentDatabase(C:\test\Open_Access.accdb).

Comment: Public Function Startup2()::Dim app As Access.Application::Set app = CreateObject("Access.Application")::app.OpenCurrentDatabase(C:\test\Open_Access.accdb):: app.Run:: I dont know what strSubName is::app.Run::app.Quit acQuitSaveNone

Comment: I thought this was it but it doesnt like this either app.OpenCurrentDatabase(C\test\Open_Access.accdb,[False],bstrPassword As String])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77910/discussion-between-pbdudley-and-akina).